# Convert list with one element to list with three elements -Python

Tags: python, list

How can I convert a list wit one element like this: `[[1.0, 0.0, nan]]` into a real list with lenght 3

```
convert `[[1.0, 0.0, nan]]`(lenght=1) into [1.0, 0.0, nan]`(lenght=3)
```

Comment: `data = data[0]`? Love how consistent you are with the "lenght" typo =) One of my favorites, as well.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485747/how-to-convert-a-nested-list-into-a-one-dimensional-list-in-python out.

Comment: You could use a list comprehension as well as the way flakes answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply access the zeroth index of your list which will give you an list of length 3

`data=data[0]`
should do the job

```
print(data) // [1.0, 0.0, nan]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just access the first value:

```
a = [[1.0, 0.0, nan]]
b = a[0]
```

Comment: why excactly i had to do this ?

Comment: @124747chdhsgxj `a` is a list of lists. To access the first list in the list of lists, you would use the square bracket `list[i]` accessor. See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list