# How to convert multiple row list to a single row list?

Tags: python, list

```
[[0, 0, 3, 50], [50, 100, 4, 20]]
```

I want to convert the above list to ,

```
[0, 0, 3, 50, 50, 100, 4, 20].
```

I tried using the split() but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485747/how-to-convert-a-nested-list-into-a-one-dimensional-list-in-python) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
list_2d = [[0, 0, 3, 50], [50, 100, 4, 20]]
list_1d = [i for nested in list_2d for i in nested]
print(list_1d)
```