# Python :: NLTK concatenating list of sentences

Tags: python, list, nltk, nested-lists

`NLTK` http://www.nltk.org/ is a toolkit for computational linguistics.

I am trying to manipulate sentences, using the `sents()` method:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
```

it fetches texts by `fileid`:

```
hamlet = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt')
```

the output is:

```
print hamlet
[['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...]
```

But let's say I want to make a list of sentences by author instead of by book. 
In a repetitive way (it won't let me `extend()` lists):

```
shakespeare = []

hamlet = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt')
macbeth = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt')
caesar = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-caesar.txt')

shakespeare.append(hamlet)
shakespeare.append(macbeth)
shakespeare.append(caesar)
```

but then it all becomes nested:

```
print shakespeare

[[['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...], [['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Macbeth', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1603', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...], [['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Julius', 'Caesar', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...]]
```

Is there a way I can end up with ONE list with all concatenated sentences, not nested, like this?

```
['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...], [['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Macbeth', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1603', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...], [['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Julius', 'Caesar', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ...]]
```

Comment: Your example at the bottom isn't a valid list.  It would help if you gave a little more info about what you are looking to achieve (and/or double-checking your example).

Comment: @Daniel there you go, I've edited the bottom example. thank you for alerting me. the syntax for the above examples are exactly right.

Comment: My pleasure - although, it's still not quite there (your example as it is written throws a `SyntaxError`).  I think I see what you are going for: it looks like you want this `['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet',` for the 1st element instead of this `[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet',` but that's just a guess.  Just saw your most recent edit, though, which makes it a lot more clear - thanks!

Comment: have you had a chance too look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176742/python-3-replacement-for-deprecated-compiler-ast-flatten-function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) after appending to your list `shakespeare`:

```
from itertools import chain

lis = list(chain.from_iterable(shakespeare))

# output:
# [
#   ['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'],
#   ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'],
#   ['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Macbeth', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1603', ']'],
#   ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'],
#   ['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Julius', 'Caesar', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'],
#   ['Actus', 'Primus', '.']
# ]
```

You could also opt for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a double-loop:

```
lis = [y for x in shakespeare for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to just fetch them all at once-- the sentences come the way you want them. The nltk's corpus readers accept either a single filename or a list of files:

```
shakespeare = gutenberg.sents(['shakespeare-hamlet.txt',
                 'shakespeare-macbeth.txt', 'shakespeare-caesar.txt'])
```

In other situations, if you have several lists and you want to concatenate them you should use `extend()`, not `append()`:

```
shakespeare.extend(macbeth)
shakespeare.extend(caesar)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree w/ Alexis that the ideal is to fetch them all at once from the gutenberg corpus.  For anyone in the future looking to concatenate sentences from separate corpuses, you could also try this pythonic approach:

```
hamlet = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt')
macbeth = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt')
caesar = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-caesar.txt')

shakespeare = hamlet + macbeth + caesar
```