# Total length of elements, and subsets, in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-length

How I can count the total elements in a dataframe, including the subset, and put the result in the new column?

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([[1, (2,5,6)], [2, (3,4)], [3, 4], [(5,6), (7,8,9)]], \
              index=range(1, len(x)+1))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': x})
```

I tried with the following code but it gives 2 in each of row:

```
df['Length'] = df['A'].apply(len)

print(df)

                         A  Length
    1       [1, (2, 5, 6)]       2
    2          [2, (3, 4)]       2
    3               [3, 4]       2
    4  [(5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]       2
```

However, what I want to get is as follow:

```
                         A  Length
    1       [1, (2, 5, 6)]       4
    2          [2, (3, 4)]       3
    3               [3, 4]       2
    4  [(5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]       5
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([[1, (2,5,6)], [2, (3,4)], [3, 4], [(5,6), (7,8,9)]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': x})
```

You can write a recursive generator that will yield `1` for each nested element that is not iterable. Something along these lines:

```
import collections 

def glen(LoS):
    def iselement(e):
        return not(isinstance(e, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(e, str))
    for el in LoS:
        if iselement(el):
            yield 1
        else:
            for sub in glen(el): yield sub    

df['Length'] = df['A'].apply(lambda e: sum(glen(e)))
```

Yielding:

```
>>> df
                     A  Length
0       [1, (2, 5, 6)]       4
1          [2, (3, 4)]       3
2               [3, 4]       2
3  [(5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]       5
```

That will work in Python 2 or 3. With Python 3.3 or later, you can use `yield from` to replace the loop:

```
def glen(LoS):
    def iselement(e):
        return not(isinstance(e, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(e, str))
    for el in LoS:
        if iselement(el):
            yield 1
        else:
            yield from glen(el)
```

Comment: Nice general answer.  I like this modification of what you've done. https://pastebin.com/TANRfyKr.  Also, my link's imports assume Python 3

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks. The original code was from an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176969/298607). There is also an improvement for Python 3.3+ to use `yield from` shown.

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools`

```
df['Length'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: len(list(itertools.chain(*x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this function, it's recursive but it works:

```
def recursive_len(item):
    try:
       iter(item)
       return sum(recursive_len(subitem) for subitem in item)
    except TypeError:
       return 1
```

Then just call the apply function this way:

```
df['Length'] = df['A'].apply(recursive_len)
```